# How to bind image gallery with sql data table in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, image, bind, image-gallery

I have binary data in SQL database of images.And there may be multiple records of any single ID.Means there may be multiple images for one ID.

> > And i have to fetch binary data of images from database and convert into image and bind with image gallery.

I am working on ASP.NET 4.0.

> > I want to do that without any third party control.

Can any one help me out on this ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to write your binary value on response using

`HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite()`

first you need to set the `ImageUrl` attribute of an `image` element to a empty `aspx` page, or an `ashx` handler, as a better choice.

and then send the `id` of record which has the binary value as `querystring` to that page, like this:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" 
    runat="server" 
    CssClass="w120px h120px" 
    ImageUrl='ImageHandler.ashx?imageID=1' />
```

and then in code behind of that specific page `(ashx handler, in our case)` you need to get binary value from your `dbase` and write to response like this:

```
public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string id = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["imageID"];
        var image = GetBinaryImageFromDataBaseByRecordID(id);
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"; // you need to set this to content-type of your image
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(image);
    }

    private byte[] GetBinaryImageFromDataBaseByRecordID(string ImageRecordID)
    {
        throw new Exception(); // you need to get binary value from db using ImageRecordID and return;
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

if you have more than one image for a subject, for example 3 images, you can use 3 `image` element, and they request to existed handler like this:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" 
    runat="server" 
    CssClass="w120px h120px" 
    ImageUrl='ImageHandler.ashx?imageID=1' />

<asp:Image ID="Image2" 
    runat="server" 
    CssClass="w120px h120px" 
    ImageUrl='ImageHandler.ashx?imageID=20' />

<asp:Image ID="Image3" 
    runat="server" 
    CssClass="w120px h120px" 
    ImageUrl='ImageHandler.ashx?imageID=30' />
```

Comment: Hi am1r_5h but we have to write binary data into images dynamically.Means we don't how much images will come for a specific ID ,initially.So we can't take image tags before getting the result.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have a page, which `id` of your subject is passed to, then in that page you need to create a `DataList` or `repeater` or some other `data` controls and get a query from `db` and bind image records of that subject to your control, and create `image` element in `DataList` or some other `data` control, for each record, and set the `ImageUrl` of image element when your `data` control `DataList, for example` is bound, something like this:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" 
RepeatColumns="4" 
RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" 
        runat="server" 
        CssClass="w120px h120px" 
        ImageUrl="ImageHandler.ashx?imageID=<%# Eval("ID") %>" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: notice: `ImageUrl` Attribute in `markup` was updated, two `quotation` mark after `=` and after `%>` , was extra.. anyhow, it is ok now

Comment: ,how we can bind datalist control with multiple images getting in imagehandler.Currently i am getting the same(last image) image in the image tag of datalist control.

Comment: check the `ImageUrl` of images on `view page source`, probably you have bound same id to each `ImageUrl`